# Scroll a specific part of a website with selenium.

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to create a script that will be used to scroll this site: http://m.1688.com/offer/39202959720.html?spm=a26g8.7664812.0.0.dfxn8I

As you can see on the site if the cursor is put inside the main space, it will be able to scroll and it wont if it's outside the main space. I created a script that i want to use to scroll the site:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Users\V\Desktop\PY\web_scrape\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('http://m.1688.com/offer/39202959720.html?spm=a26g8.7664812.0.0.dfxn8I')
displayed = False
for i in range(5):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(2)
```

Assuming all the related packages are imported, when the script runs, it appears that selenium isnt scrolling the site and i would like to know what can i do to fix that. Maybe there are some ways that i can tell selenium to put the cursor in a specific part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use below code to scroll content down:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver.get('http://m.1688.com/offer/39202959720.html?spm=a26g8.7664812.0.0.dfxn8I')

# Click on element inside the main content to switch focus
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h1[@class="d-title"]').click()

for i in range(5):
    # Scroll page down
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.END)
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Is there any way for it to scroll just a little bit instead of all the way to the end because when i implement the code, it doesnt print out a few elements.

Comment: To go a certain way down, you can change your original javascript to: `driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,window.innerHeight * 0.9);")` and change 0.9 to whatever fraction of the screen you want to scroll down.

Comment: @V.Anh, you can replace `driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.END)` with `driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.DOWN)` and use it several times to make just little scrolls

Comment: @Andersson It worked but i dont understand why i have to look at the web page directly when the Chrome instance is opened in order to get all the elements and when i use PhantomJS, it doesnt return the same result as Chromedriver.

Comment: @V.Anh `PhantomJS` is quite specific tool and its behavior is slightly different in handling XHR. I advise you to use `PhantomJS` only in case of great need)

Comment: @Andersson I understand but in case of Chromedriver, how can i use it to get every elements without directly looking at it on screen ?

Comment: @V.Anh, I'm not sure I can understand the problem completely as I don't understand the content ot the source page (it seem to be on Chinese). If you need just to *get some specific data*, but not *to test the web page* you can avoid using `selenium` and look towards `HTTP` libraries like [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) or [`urllib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html) to make appropriate `HTTP` requests and get required data

Comment: @Andersson I mean that when i use selenium, beautifulsoup to get the page source, the script will open the chrome browser and automate the page. If i have the browser visible on my screen, it will extract without any problem but if i minimize the browser, it will just extract the same element over and over again without loading the new content. I think it happens to all other website when i use Chromedriver.

Comment: @V.Anh Not always you can scrape only data that is currently visible. But actually it's normal as `selenium` allows you to simulate exact user behavior. When you use browser manually you can see data that currently displayed on page and you should scroll to get more- same with `selenium`...